# Use a match function to find the text to use as file name

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a match function to reference a cell which contains the new file name.

```
Sub SaveAs()

    Dim FName           As String
    Dim FPath           As String
    Dim NewBook         As Workbook

    FPath = "\\G:\Exceptions"
    FName = (Application.Match("Test", Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1:A42"), 0, 2)) & ".xls"

    If Dir(FPath & "\" & FName) <> "" Then
        MsgBox "File " & FPath & "\" & FName & " already exists"
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=FPath & "\" & FName
    End If

End Sub
```

Can this be done or am I better to find another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on Scott's answer:

A first Error is with your Match.

```
Application.Match("Test", Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1:A42"), 0, 2))
```

needs to become

```
Application.Worksheetfunction.Match("Test", Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1:A42"), 0)
```

Also Match returns only a long so you need to add `Cells()` to find the name you need

`Cells(Application.Worksheetfunction.Match("Test", Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1:A42"), 0),2).value`

gives you the name you need

Now if you add the case where the match is not found you end up with this code:

```
Sub SaveAs()

    Dim FName           As String
    Dim FPath           As String
    Dim NewBook         As Workbook
    Dim Mtch            As Long

    FPath = "\\G:\Exceptions"
    Mtch = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Test", Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1:A42"), 0)
    FName = Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Test", Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1:A42"), 0), 2) & ".xls"
    MsgBox FName

    If Not IsError(Mtch) Then
        If Dir(FPath & "\" & Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(Mtch, 1).Value) <> "" Then
            MsgBox "File " & FPath & "\" & FName & " already exists"
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "the value not found in the column"
    End If

End Sub
```

Alternatively you can also find the Row like this:

```
Mtch = Findval("TEST", Range("A1:A42"))

MsgBox Mtch
FName = Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Test", Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1:A42"), 0), 2) & ".xls"
MsgBox FName


If Not IsError(Mtch) Then
    If Dir(FPath & "\" & Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(Mtch, 1).Value) <> "" Then
        MsgBox "File " & FPath & "\" & FName & " already exists"
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "the value not found in the column"
End If

End Sub


Function Findval(VALUESEARCHED As String, ra As Range) As Variant

Dim A As Range

    Set A = ra.Find(What:=VALUESEARCHED, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

Findval = A.Row

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @Pierre44 however I still get a compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment Is this to do with the match?

Comment: I m gonna test it now :) Where do you get your error?

Comment: When it gets to MATCH

Cells(Application.Worksheetfunction.Match("Test", Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1:A42"), 0),2).value

Comment: Your "Sheet 1" Doesn t exist I guess. Is your Sheet not named "Sheet1" (no space)

Comment: You are correct that it should be Sheet1 however still the same error. "Compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

Comment: Worked!! Thank you so very much for all you help. 
One note: I removed the MsgBox Mtch line as it was not necessary for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Match returns a Long, the relative location in the 1 dimensional range.  You will need to use that number with something else, like `Cells()` to return the actual name.

```
Sub SaveAs()

    Dim Mtch as Long
    Dim FPath           As String
    Dim NewBook         As Workbook

    FPath = "\\G:\Exceptions"
    Mtch = (Application.Match("Test", Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1:A42"), 0)) & ".xls"

    If Dir(FPath & "\" & Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(Mtch,2).Value) <> "" Then
        MsgBox "File " & FPath & "\" & FName & " already exists"
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=FPath & "\" & FName
    End If

End Sub
```

Now another thing.  You will want to deal with the error if a match is not found:

```
Sub SaveAs()

    Dim Mtch as Variant
    Dim FPath           As String
    Dim NewBook         As Workbook

    FPath = "\\G:\Exceptions"
    Mtch = (Application.Match("Test", Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1:A42"), 0)) & ".xls"
    If not iserror(mtch) then
        If Dir(FPath & "\" & Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(Mtch,2).Value) <> "" Then
            MsgBox "File " & FPath & "\" & FName & " already exists"
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=FPath & "\" & FName
        End If
    Else
        msgbox "the value not found in the column
    End if

End Sub
```

Comment: I don t know if my answer complete yours or is actually stealing your work. In that case you can edit your answer and I will delete mine ;)

Comment: Nope, but You are more correct than me, I will need to edit.  If you add about the error handling I will delete mine.

Comment: Thank you both. I have not 100% got it working yet but your input is invaluable.